# Why does my program print "invalid Username or Password" when it's correct

Tags: python-3.x, authentication

I have tried many different imputs but they all say print "Invalid". I would appreciate if anyone can explain or edit my code so i can understand.

```
username = []
password = []

def account_creation():
    account = input("Would you like to make an Account? Yes or No: ")
    if account == "Yes" or "yes":
        username = input("Please make a Username: ")
        password = input("Please make a Password: ")
    else:
        return
account_creation()

def login():
    account = input("Do you have an Account? Yes or No: ")
    if account == "Yes":
        login_username = input("Plese enter your username: ")
        login_password = input("Plese enter your password: ")
    else:
        return
    if login_username and login_password == username and password:
        print("Welcome back")
    else:
        print("Invalid Username or Password")

login()
```

Comment: Your code will print "welcome back" if `login-username==True` and `login_password==username` and `password==True`. it should be `login_username == username and login_password == password`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that, it confused me but now i understand where I went wrong.

Comment: Could you clarify though where i need to add each new part? i'm slightly confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to first check you username-password check line (as _venky stated):

```
...    
if login_username == username and login_password == password:
...
```

but you have something more important missing here.
you are trying to change global variables inside a function, thus you need `global` keyword with related variables in the function body.

```
def account_creation():
    global username,password
    account = ... the rest of the code
```

Comment: So I understand the need for the global variable but what do I need to check in the username-password check line?

Comment: venky had already given that part but I thought I should add that too here. I guess you wrote this while I was editing.

Comment: i've done both the username-password check line and the global variable but it still seems to print invalid username or password and i've done multiple tests.

Comment: I am sure you messed somewhere else while trying to correct. just copy-paste your own code in your question, then patch the parts I gave you. I have changed only those parts and it is working surely. If you are on linux I recommend you to do a diff test to see where things went wrong

Comment: It's working now!! I think I just accidentally messed up somewhere. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: you may flag the answer as accepted if you pleased. thanks

Comment: @Owain1105 please accept Yilmaz's answer if it helped you.